# How to create a subcategory to a PAGE on WP?

Tags: categories, pages, directory, sub-menu

I have a URL: www.example.com/banana-lp

and I want to change it's URL to www.example.com/lp/banana

I have been searching for how to do this everywhere but only found how to get this done by "posts" and not "pages".

Comment: So you have a page with slug 'banana-lp' and you want to make it 'lp/banana', that mean you will more pages under 'lp' right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very simple way to do this:

1. Make a page with slug 'lp' or whatever you want
2. Then create page with slug 'banana' and set the previously created page 'lp' as it's parent from the parent dropdown list.
3. Do the same process for other pages whom you want to display like 'lp/otherpages'

You can also add category support for pages via coding but I think the above points will solve your problem.